# How to remove phrase and then 2 characters following it?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string similar to the following

circles_b2_test_20130206_rem01_toy.jpg

I'd like it to look like

circles_b2_test_20130206_toy.jpg

How can I remove only the "rem01" phrase? The numbers after rem are always changing but I always want to remove "rem" + 2 characters.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried already for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's rem + two characters then you can use `rem.{2}`.

If it's rem + two digits then you can use `rem\d{2}`.

Note if you want `circles_b2_test_20130206_toy.jpg` then you need to check the `_` in front of `01`, you could try with:

```
import re
file = 'circles_b2_test_20130206_rem01_toy.jpg'
re.sub(r'rem\d{2}_?', '', file)
# 'circles_b2_test_20130206_toy.jpg'
```

Comment: I think you meant to pass `file` as the third argument

Comment: Yei, thanks @Dor-Ron

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A bit "hacky," but this should achieve what you're after if there are always 2 numbers after the *rem*

```
str = "circles_b2_test_20130206_rem01_toy.jpg"
idx = str.index("rem")
new_str = str[:idx] + str[idx+6:]
```